# Next.js 13 - /_next/static 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nextjs, next.js, next

Обновлял next.js с 12 на 13 версию. При dev режиме всё работает. При build начинает выпадать ошибка 404 на папку static. Прокидываются прокси через nginx и как костыльное решение был добавлен алиас

```
location /_next/static {
    alias <путь>/.next/static;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
}
```

Смотря офф документацию, next должен был проделывать это автоматически, но при переходе на 13 версию никакие конфиги не менялись, оно просто отпало, может есть какое-то более изящное решение?

Comment: а откуда взялся урл `_next` вообще? что в 12 что в 13 нексте папка `.next`

Comment: На любом сайте который сделан на next, открываешь консоль разработчика и вкладка "sources" и вот оттуда берётся, офф дока https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/production-checklist

Comment: как конкретно происходило "обновление"? alias стоит убрать. Если создать новое приложение в 13 версии - ошибка воспроизводится?

Comment: решили ли проблему? у меня подобное возникало из-за настроек сервера в нгинкс и таким образом решилось, прописав локейшен но без алиаса и заголовка.